# How to design Gray code synchronous counters of large widths using SystemVerilog?

Tags: digital-logic, counter, system-verilog, rtl, sequential-logic

I want to design a synchronous gray code counter which is 10 bits wide in SystemVerilog. The counter should have an Active HIGH synchronous reset.

I know how to design a 3 bit gray code counter like this:

```
module gray_code3(input logic reset, clk, output logic [2:0]q); 
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
if (reset)
 q <= 0;
else
  case (q)
   3'b000:  q <= 3'b001;
   3'b001:  q <= 3'b011;
   3'b011:  q <= 3'b010;
   3'b010:  q <= 3'b110;
   3'b110:  q <= 3'b111;
   3'b111:  q <= 3'b101;
   3'b101:  q <= 3'b100;
   3'b100:  q <= 3'b000;
   default: q <= 3'bx;
  endcase
end
endmodule
```

Using the same technique would be very tedious for gray code counter of large widths. How to design gray code counters of large widths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design is partitioned into 2 parts - one for combinational logic and another for sequential logic.

1. In the sequential logic part, an always_ff block is used. Counter is an internal signal used to store the values and it gets incremented on the positive edge of the clock. Counter is a binary counter, and it has a modulus of 2 raised to the power of its width.
2. In the combinational logic part, an always_comb block is used, where the binary code to gray code conversion is done. This is done by observing two facts:

   1. The Most Significant Bit is the same as the Most Significant Bit of the binary counter. This assignment can be done using an assign statement.
   2. For other bits, they are the result of the Ex-Or operation on the
      corresponding bit of the binary counter and the bit to the immediate right of it. Hence a foreach loop is suitable to iterate over all the bits and perform the Ex-Or operation over the respective bits of the binary counter.

**Design:**

```
module gray_ctr
  #(parameter WIDTH=4)
  (input logic clk,                
    input logic reset,
    output logic [WIDTH-1:0] q);    
   
  logic [WIDTH-1:0] counter;
  
  always_ff @ (posedge clk) begin
    if (reset) begin
      counter <= 0;
    end  
    else begin
      counter <= counter + 1;    
    end  
  end
   
  always_comb begin
  q[WIDTH-1] = counter[WIDTH-1];
  foreach (counter[i]) 
    q[i-1] = counter[i]^counter[i-1]; 
  end  
  
endmodule
```

**Testbench:**

```
module tb;
  parameter WIDTH = 4;
  
  reg clk;
  reg rstn;
  wire [WIDTH-1:0] out;
  
  gray_ctr #(WIDTH) u0 (.clk (clk),
                .reset (rstn),
                .q (out));
  
  always #10 clk = ~clk;
  
  initial begin
    {clk, rstn} = 0;
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars(1,tb);                
    $monitor ("T=%0t out=%b", $time, out);
    #50 rstn = 1;
    #50 rstn = 0;
    #50 rstn = 1;
    #50 rstn = 0;
    #800 
    $finish;
  end
  
endmodule
```

Comment: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/rja - EDA playground link

Comment: 1) You can replace the `for` loop with simply `q = (counter >> 1) ^ counter;`. Might be more obvious to the synthesis tool what to infer as it's self contained. 2) A note on naming conventions, `q` usually implies a register.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, @awjlogan. This line ```q = (counter >> 1) ^ counter;``` is an eye-opener for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well its verilog, but my solution is:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

/*
 * Simple, variable Width, Grey-Up-Counter
 */
module counter_grey #(
  parameter MAX_VALUE = 128
)(
    input        clk,
    input        reset,
    input        cnt,
    output [(($clog2(MAX_VALUE))-1):0] value
);       

assign value = dec_value ^ (dec_value>>1);

reg [(($clog2(MAX_VALUE))-1):0] dec_value;

/*
 *
*/
always@(posedge clk) begin
    if(reset) begin
        dec_value <= 0;
    end
    else if(cnt) begin
      if(dec_value < MAX_VALUE)
        dec_value <= dec_value + 1;
      else
        dec_value <= 0;
      end    
end
   
endmodule
```

With the important line is:

assign value = dec_value ^ (dec_value>>1);

that's makes it a greycode counter,... the rest of code is just a paste n copy of a decimal counter

Comment: Your solution is right, but could you please tell me how it is a **decimal** counter? It looks like a **binary counter** with a **binary to gray converter**.

Comment: Maybe my use of the word decimal is wrong here... it counts normal integers from 0...(Max_Value-1) its not like binary coded decimals...

Comment: Yes, we usually use the term binary since it has to be converted to decimal.